# Adding a SVG image to symbol in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to set the symbol of the context menu using this :
Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.symbol = url('path to a external link');
This way I am able to change the icon of 'symbol'.

Now I want to use a SVG image in my workspace 
Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.symbol = url('path to img file in repo');
How do I set the path to a SVG image in my local repo?

Answer (score 0):

The export button is rendered as an SVG path, so it can't be overridden by CSS.

Here is a guideline how to use custom symbols: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.symbol